# How to remove new buttons from inline lookup crm 2013/2016?

Tags: inline, lookup, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there any Supported / Unsupported ways to remove new buttons from inline lookup in crm 2013/ 2016 ?

I don't want to do it via security role way.

Also from the loop up window?

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported way apart from what you mention: Remove the Create privilege for the given entity.

Comment: Thanks for the response Henrik

Answer (score 1):

Strictly unsupported, but doable via straight DOM manipulation.

I don't have working code at hand, but the ID of what you need to hide is `Dialog_<AttributeName>_IMenu` in CRM 2016 Update 1